# Правильная выгрузка DLL

Tags: c++, dll

Делаю следующие события:

1. Есть мое приложение, в "запущенном виде".
2. Я в это приложение делаю инъекцию "DLL".
3. Отлаживаю баги, смотрю нужные мне штуки.
4. Выгружаю DLL из приложения.

Вопрос вот в чем, как правильно выгрузить эту DLL, делаю так:

```
void StartThread(const HINSTANCE& hinstDLL) {
//...манипуляции с приложением..
    while (условие_какое-то)
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hinstDLL, 0);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH://Вызывается первым 
        StartThread(hinstDLL);
        return 1;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH://вызывается после освобождения библиотеки
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH://вызывается при создании потока
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH://вызывается после разрушения потока
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Вроде бы выгружает корректно, но я не уверен что все делаю правильно, пожалуйста подскажите правильную последовательность событий.

Comment: Допишите вопрос, что Вы «не у»? :)

Comment: @ixSci - дописал.

Answer (score 2):

Операционная система самостоятельно следит за загруженными библиотеками. И если в программе подключается библиотека , ОС загружает ее в память и предоставляет различным программа. Поэтому в программе нет необходимости выгружать библиотеку.

Comment: дело в том, что мне необходимо выгрузить эту библиотеку в определенный момент и продолжить работу с программой.

Comment: В linux у загруженой библиотеки,  есть счетчик ссылок приложений которые используют эту библиотеку и когда счетчик равен 0, библиотека выгружается из памяти. Но может и не выгрузит если есть пямять.

Comment: я пока что только в windows работаю,