# Использование подгрузки mscorlib.dll при запуске программы не из GAC

Tags: c#, .net, mono, runtime, assembly

моя проблема в том, что я бы хотел, чтобы при запуске программы  загружалась mscorlib.dll не из GAC, а моя, идентичная по версии и публичному ключу.

Для этого я сделал следующее :
Использовал : в обозначенный каталог были загружены различные System*.dll идентичные по внешним признакам с используемыми в FrameWork, видно, что при запуске приложения они подгружаются именно оттуда, а не из GAC.
Туда же поместил mscorlib, однако, загрузка его не происходит. По умолчанию продолжает загружаться из GAC.

В файле с конфигурацией exe файла прописывал, такие параметры для загрузки, как :

```
<developmentMode developerInstallation="true"/>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="mscorlib"
                              publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"
                              culture="neutral" />

            <codeBase version="4.0.0.0"
                     href="file:///D:\DEVPATH\mscorlib.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
```

Однако желаемого результата не получаю, поэтому хочу узнать возможно ли добится этого?

Мое окружение : win10, framework 4.8
Подгружаемые dll: частично Mono + .NET Core

Информация о :  developmentMode
(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/developmentmode-element)

Comment: Приложение ваше? Или чужое? По идее используя WinAPI можно выгрузить эту библиотеку, и загрузить заново. Или перехваты других WinAPI, подмена их функций, загрузка своей либы и замен обратно? Но я так понимаю это слишком громоздко?  А что это за библиотека вообще?

Comment: Приложение мое, пока простенькое тестовое.
Все это делается для того, чтобы иметь возможность качественной отладки и доработки подменяемых dll. Сами dll берутся из большей частью из  Mono. Mscorlib - ядро (Microsoft Common Object Runtime Library)

Comment: Для C++ видел примеры Загрузки\Выгрузки dll. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516565/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-dll) и [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1739167.html)

Comment: Спасибо, главная проблема, в том, подменяемая библиотека является ядром для C#, где описаны базовые классы и т.д

Пробовал использую csc (компилятор для framework)  указывать в параметрах  -nostdlib дабы не использывать библиотеку mscorlib штатную, при этом указывая свою в reference. Однако, не получилось добится того, чтобы при запуске загружалась только нужная мне mscorlib